# Secure Gmail login on web browser from external Java program

Tags: java, gmail, browser

Is there a secure way of logging into a Gmail account on a web browser, from an external Java program? I know the following works, but is there a safer alternative?

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(
        "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?continue=http://mail.google.com/gmail" +
        "&service=mail&Email=LOGIN&Passwd=PASSWORD&null=Sign+in"));
```

**Clarification**: The external Java program is [GmailAssistant](http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/), a Gmail notifier that already uses the IMAP capabilities of JavaMail. I just need a way of allowing the user to access the account directly in a web browser.

Answer (score 3):

Depending of how much you want to integrate, you can check Google single sign-on (SSO) api. I'm studing how to use it and the best way to integrate it

http://code.google.com/apis/apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html

Victor

UPDATED:

As a better option, you should check this link as well http://esoeproject.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you're really wanting to control a browser from Java, you'll have to use a web-connector such as [Selenium](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/) or [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/).  Both of these let you control a browser directly from within Java and simulate a user typing text, clicking on links and submitting forms.  One thing to keep in mind when doing this with Selenium is that it interacts with a complete new profile which is usually independent of your standard Firefox probile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid that the link is visible in the Page, create a javascript document that sends a POST request to the server.

Comment: He said Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: He's suggesting creating a HTML file with the embedded javascript. The JS POSTs to Google on load, the Java program tells the browser to open the snippet file.

Comment: Does that mean that the JS file would need to contain the login credentials, or can I pass those into the browser dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically access the content of a GMail account, I would strongly suggest to use the [IMAP access provided by Google](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725).

Looking at the question the other way around, you can setup an [OpenID](http://openid-provider.appspot.com/) authentication scheme based on your Google account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already use JavaMail to connect to the account via IMAP (see clarification in question).

Answer (score 0):

I used google's IMAP access with the JavaMail API, and it was very simple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already use JavaMail to connect to the account via IMAP (see clarification in question).

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the URL being sent for the login, understand that:

1. https:// starts with www.google.com and will encrypt the session *before*
2. sending the login details (or even the page it's going to